# Xorg.0.log is not updating or missing on Arch

Tags: xorg

The last `Xorg.0.log` file I have is from Dec 1, 2017 in `/var/log/`
I'm on Archlinux using i3wm.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root xtian            36K Dec  1  2017 Xorg.0.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root xtian            34K Nov  9  2017 Xorg.0.log.bak
-rw-r--r--  1 root xtian            37K Nov 29  2017 Xorg.0.log.old
-rw-r--r--  1 root bumblebee        13K Nov 22  2017 Xorg.8.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root bumblebee        13K Nov 13  2017 Xorg.8.log.bak
-rw-r--r--  1 root bumblebee        13K Nov 18  2017 Xorg.8.log.old
```

- dmesg  doesn't have any instance of `Xorg.0.log`
- journalctl has a record of me moving Xorg.0.log to the .bak file in Nov, but that's about it.

This was a new install in September 2017(?) on Lenovo W541. This laptop has Nvidia and built in Intel graphics, and I was having a lot of trouble with backlight that was too bright using Nvidia. I'm using only the Intel.

Troubleshooting a Multihead setup, I just noticed today that Xorg.o.log hasn't been written since last year.

How do I go about troubleshooting this to get the log file back in order?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#General), your log is in `$HOME/.local/share/xorg/`:

> If a problem occurs, view the log stored in either /var/log/ or, *for
>   the rootless X default since v1.16*, in `~/.local/share/xorg/`

Comment: Also true for Fedora 30.